# Use of an overloaded operator in a scoped enum definition

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, scoped-enums

Given this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

enum class Enum;

constexpr Enum operator~(Enum) { return static_cast<Enum>(5); }

enum class Enum { A = 1, B = ~Enum::A }; // line 8
//                            ^^^^^^^

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{} and {}\n",
        static_cast<int>(Enum::B), static_cast<int>(~Enum::A));
}
```

is there a way to tell the compiler not to treat `Enum::A` on line 8 as `int`, but rather as of type `Enum`? In other words, to force the compiler to use the custom `operator~()`. This program outputs `-2 and 5`.

Comment: This worked for me: `enum class Enum { A = 1, B = static_cast<int>(~static_cast<Enum>(Enum::A)) };`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zGdvjvM7f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not really](https://eel.is/c++draft/enum#dcl.enum-5.sentence-7)

> If the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is the underlying type and the constant-expression in the enumerator-definition shall be a converted constant expression of the underlying type.

If you want to execute some custom logic reliably, lift it out of the operator into a constexpr named function the accepts that the underlying type, then reuse it for both the enum declaration and the operator definition.

Answer (score 2):

Extra casting does the job:

```
enum class Enum {
    A = 1,
    B = static_cast<int>(~Enum(Enum::A))
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b4P3ehe6G)

Comment: Why is it necessary though?

Comment: @user17732522: I don't know.

Comment: Yep, this works, thanks! But it is not really the way I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to tell the compiler that. The restrictions on the type of the *constant-expression* after the `=` are laid out in [[dcl.enum] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#5):

- If the underlying type is fixed (in your case, it is fixed), the type of the *constant-expression* is the underlying type (implicitly `int` in your case).

  - The underlying type must be an integral type, so you're out of luck.
- If it isn't fixed, then it must be an integral constant expression.

In any case, `B = ~Enum::A` isn't valid. I was unable to find any proposal that would make this syntax valid either.
The cleanest way would be to use `std::to_underlying` in C++23:

```cpp
enum class Enum {
    A = 1,
    B = std::to_underlying(~Enum{A}) // note: A refers to 1, not Enum{1} here
};
```